# Jenkinsfile to checkout multiple branches

Tags: git, jenkins

Currently our Jenkinsfile has the `checkout scm` step. This results in only one detached head branch:

```
$ git branch
* (HEAD detached at 174e48797a)
```

Is there a way we can go a proper fetch to get multiple branches checked out?

```
$ git branch
* dev
  master
  testing
```

We would like to do processing in our pipeline to compare differences between the dev and testing/master branches

Additionally, we use the BitBucket git plugin so the access token is store in Jenkins credentials

Comment: What do you mean by "to get multiple branches checked out?" You can only checkout one branch/tree at a time. If you'd like to diff two branches, you can do something like `git diff branch_1..branch_2`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that worked for me at https://alanedwardes.com/blog/posts/git-username-password-environment-variables

Replacing

```
sh 'git push origin my-tag'
```

with

```
sh 'git pull --all'
```

--all pulls down all the branches.

Once done I can successfully do git diff branch..branch